# Group by and average on subquery Bigquery

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery, average

I am trying to group records by date and for that particular day, get the average of of one of the columns called latency. I have the following standardSQL query which works but doesnt when I try to get avg of and group by of table:

```
SELECT * 
From 
(
SELECT 'ADS-B Average Latency for Asia' as metric_name, 'Daily' as metric_period_type,
  DATE(timestamp) as metric_date, collection_type, UNIX_SECONDS(ingestion_time) - UNIX_SECONDS(timestamp) as latency
  FROM `analytics.aoi_table` a
  order by metric_date
) table
```

This is the table: 
[image]

When I try to do avg and group by of the table above using sql below, I get the following error: Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword GROUP at [10:3]

SQL that causes error:

```
#standardSQL

SELECT * 
From 
(
SELECT 'ADS-B Average Latency for Asia' as metric_name,
  DATE(timestamp) as metric_date, collection_type, AVG(UNIX_SECONDS(ingestion_time) - UNIX_SECONDS(timestamp)) as latency
  FROM `ais-data-analysis.customer_analytics.itochu_aoi_table` a
  order by metric_date
  group by metric_date, collection_type
) table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `order by` clause goes after the `group by` clause. Also, there is no need to wrap your query, you can just do:

```
SELECT 
    'ADS-B Average Latency for Asia' as metric_name,
    DATE(timestamp) as metric_date, 
    collection_type, 
    AVG(UNIX_SECONDS(ingestion_time) - UNIX_SECONDS(timestamp)) as latency
FROM `ais-data-analysis.customer_analytics.itochu_aoi_table` a
GROUP BY metric_date, collection_type
ORDER BY metric_date, collection_type
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `group by` and `order by` are out of sequence.  In addition, you don't need the subquery:

```
select 'ADS-B Average Latency for Asia' as metric_name,
       DATE(timestamp) as metric_date, collection_type, AVG(UNIX_SECONDS(ingestion_time) - UNIX_SECONDS(timestamp)) as latency
from `ais-data-analysis.customer_analytics.itochu_aoi_table` a
group by metric_date, collection_type
order by metric_date
```